# May I use relay rated for 5A to switch 12A?

Tags: relay, h-bridge, mechanical

I would like to use an electromechanical relay as an H-bridge, which is capable to drive 12A at 12V.

Relays able to control this current are big and expensive.

Is it ok to use a compact relay with nominal max switching current 5A if I promise to switch it over always at zero current?

Comment: Promises, promises...

Comment: You should look into parts intended for automotive applications, which are relatively cheap.

Comment: @DaveTweed, and guaranteed to fail two days after your warranty expires ;)

Comment: @Trevor my 18 year old daily driver has yet to have a faulty relay.  I know 50 year old cars with original relays and fuses.

Comment: @Passerby.. it was a joke ...

Comment: Where's the funny?

Comment: Can you promise no oxidation and contact resistance rise?

Comment: I bought a 70A relay (12V coil voltage) for about $3 from a small electronics hardware store, so not really "expensive"

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/121779644442?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_noapp=true
12 bucks for a 35 amp H-bridge relay.

Comment: Starting at $2.07 for an individual 12V 12A relay.
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/power-relays-over-2-amps/188?FV=ffe000bc%2C1200002%2C120001b%2Cmu12A%7C1410&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Comment: @Passerby Between the lines. Takes a certain mindset to see it. ;-)

Comment: Just another question about the original question... What frequency are you looking to potentially switch this H bridge at? And what is the load? Motor loads will typically have a very high inrush current, especially when reversing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likley not. The relay rating depends on both losses and actual breaking capability. Check the contact resistance and calculate I^2*R. You'll end up with a big number.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other great answers: **It depends on the relay.**

If the relays spec sheet only specifies a switching current, then it's not a great idea. If however it shows a max current separately from the switching current, then change-over at zero or low current is acceptable.

**HOWEVER:** You also have to take into account whether you can guarantee switching will never occur when current is flowing, for example, when the power goes out. A one time event like that can fuse your contacts together.

Answer (score 0):

Aging from Arrhenius effects of temp rise from contact resistance and excessive conduction current in addition to unspecified reactive loads can be predicted to last a very short time. Normally Relays are rated for >=1 million mechanical switches and 50k at worst case ratings from the best suppliers (OMRON)

But with your application I could probably burn it out at 500Hz rate using NC contact to interrupt coil current in about 3 minutes. Your mileage will vary.

For more learned Engineer, read [this](http://www.omron.com.au/service_support/technical_guide/general_purpose_relay/further_information.asp)

This tells every aspect of Relay design for general purpose types.

Automotive Relays are designed to cycle perhaps every 5 minutes for a 15A radiator fan using a 20A breaker.  The contact resistance varies with material type. Contacts may have  with alloy layers Palladium, tungsten, nickel plated with silver or not.  Many variables . Always derate with DC current and reactive loads !! read OMRON detailed component specs for these values.  Many other less reputable companies may not have this data.

### FYI

All relays rated < 2A are gold plated for microcurrent due to oxidation and current required to wet contacts ( usually 10%)  This microplating would obviously burn up with high arc currents.  Power Relays are defined by ratings >2A are not gold plated but depending on vendor quality have temperature resistance materials with excellent contact design.  (See link)

### Added info

If can you guarantee zero switching current, you may get longer life than minimal and have an exceptional circumstance. But this is not a good design practise.

Switching delays cannot guarantee Zero current for AC loads even with a ZCS pulse triggered off. Normally it is the switched arc current which determines additional contact temperature rise while steady current temp rise may be good at first.  Long idle periods with oxidation buildup can then aggravate the thermal rise.

So it depends why you are doing this compromise on integrity when 25A 12V contact relays are cheap.